# Only update the field where new value bigger than old - DynamoDB - Lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a Table in DynamoD with structure:
[image]

Now, when a user call my lambda function and put a new score.
In that case, I have to update the field which the new value is bigger than the old value.

**Example**:
 Current value of s1: 6354, s10:1513, s1001:328

If user send a new value: s1: 1000, s10:2000, s1001:4567

I expect will replace the score of s1 and replace the value of s10 and s1001. So the new value of item in table must be:
   s1: 6354  , s10: 2000 ,   s1001: 4567

I read the AWS document, but I understood that when I check the updated condition, I only have 2 option: replace the current item  by new item (which field in params when updateItem) or keep the current item.

So, please let me know there is any solution for this problem? 
Thanks!

Comment: Can you share object which you are sending to update function?

Comment: I think you have to scan to get the current value in DB. After that compare current value with sent value to make new data by logic keeping bigger. And use updateItem to update curent value by new value.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are also taking the new values in dynamodb in **new** key and your previous values in **temp** key which actually are in facebook Id string[image], you can do it like this using python in lambda:

```
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')
response_old = dynamodb.get_item(
    TableName='test',
    Key={'name': {'S': 'temp'}}              
    )
response_new = dynamodb.get_item(
    TableName='test',
    Key={'name': {'S': 'new'}}              
    )

olds1001=response_old['Item']['s1001']['N']
olds10=response_old['Item']['s10']['N']
olds1=response_old['Item']['s1']['N']

news1001=response_new['Item']['s1001']['N']
news10=response_new['Item']['s10']['N']
news1=response_new['Item']['s1']['N']


if (olds1001>news1001):
    news1001=olds1001
if (olds10>news10):
    news10=olds10
if (olds1>news1):
    news1=olds1

dynamodb.put_item(
        TableName='test',
        Item={
            'name': {'S': 'temp'},
            's1': {'N': news1},
            's10': {'N': news10},
            's1001': {'N': news1001}
        })
```

updated table will be like this

[image]